# ComputerVisionErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

When I run the project  named "4 - CognitiveServices" in githup of https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Samples/tree/master/build2019/csharp, the window will show exception, and I checked my key and endpoint, please see the pic:

Error Details:

[image]

Comment: What value did you put for your endpoint?

Comment: https://koreacentral.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/

Comment: You replaced the value here? did you let the "/" at the end? https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Samples/blob/master/build2019/csharp/4%20-%20CognitiveServices/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L121

Comment: It seems that it is because my SDK version is not correct, now it can run normally, thank you!